# How to do join fetching instead of select fectching with EclipseLink?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, fetch

I've got a **OneToOne** relation between two entities. This relation is eager by default, but when logging requests, I only see **multiple selects, no join** appears. Same thing when forcing eager.

Do you know how to tell eclipselink to use join fetching (like @Fetch(JOIN) in hibernate) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@JoinFetch

or,

@JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.OUTER)

you can also use,

@BatchFetch

See,
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2010/08/batch-fetching-optimizing-object-graph.html

You can also set both of these through Query hints instead of always having it enabled.