# How to fetch lazy attributes in collection of entities, by not doing N calls to database

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

How to fetch lazy attributes in collection of entities, by not doing N calls to database. Example:

```java
transactions = getTransactionsBySomeCriteriaApiQuery(..); // n transactions
// this make 3*n calls to DB, I want to do only a few calls
transactions.forEach(res -> {
  res.getLazyCollection1().size();
  res.getLazyCollection2().size();
  res.getLazyCollection3().size();
});
return transactions;
```

Assume n is big number.
I would like to know if it is possible to fetch that lazy data by not making huge amount of calls to DB. I am using JPA (eclipselink), relational database.

**EDIT**: Indeed it is N+1 selects problem, and i would like to know how it can be resolved in eclipselink. Note that I do not want to change entity mappings from lazy to eager, because it is needed in other places. I have tried to use fetch joins (fetch on criteriaAPI), but this not working when used more than one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "N+1 selects problem" in ORM (Object-Relational Mapping)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping)

Comment: show what you've tried, but JPA has issues allowing nesting fetch joins. See http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2010/08/batch-fetching-optimizing-object-graph.html from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4680802/496099 .

Comment: My teammate managed to resolve this by using @NamedEntityGraph and QueryHints.JPA_LOAD_GRAPH, when I'll have time I will write the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use FETCH JOIN to retrieve the actually required data in initial query.

Comment: I have tried, and it seems to not work. I was doing few fetch joins in criteria API, each for each lazy relationship. It seems to working when used only for one lazy relationship

Comment: ```From<TransactionEntity, TransactionEntity> from = ...
from.fetch("lazyCollection1");
from.fetch("lazyCollection2");
from.fetch("lazyCollection3");```